# Как правильно согласовать в числе однородные подлежащие со сказуемым?

Tags: синтаксис

Как быть в следующей ситуации:
«Выдача справок, а также консультация по вопросам жилищного права осуществляЕТ(ЮТ)ся в  указанные часы»? Какое число все-таки должно быть у сказуемого?

Розенталь, конечно, говорит о согласовании однородных подлежащих, связанных союзом А ТАКЖЕ, со сказуемым, но его пример касается очевидного случая присоединения (конец предложения): «В Бельгию экспортирован лён, а также лесные товары». Розенталь поясняет: "Если между однородными подлежащими стоит присоединительный союз, то сказуемое согласуется с ближайшим подлежащим". А если данное предложение построить так: «Лесные товары, а также лен…»?

Заранее благодарю за обстоятельный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласование сказуемого с несколькими  подлежащими действительно вызывает сложность. 
В речи возможны оба варианта. Но форма множественного числа сказуемого преобладает, что связано с общей тенденцией к согласованию по смыслу сказуемого с подлежащим. Особенно эта тенденция сильна в текстах публицистического и делового стилей. Поскольку Ваш пример как раз такого рода, правильней будет употребить форму множественного числа.

Comment: если можно, очень хотелось бы получить соответствующие ссылки на источники

Answer (score 1):

Небольшое уточнение: в рассмотренном случае возможны оба варианта, т.к. подлежащие относятся одному грамматическому роду - женскому. Если же они разного рода, то возможно только множественное число сказуемого, поскольку подлежащие относятся к нему в равной степени - они же однородные. Приоритет здесь невозможен. Ни по какому признаку.

Лучший источник - школьные учебники для 8 и 9 классов

Comment: «Выдача справок, а также консультация по вопросам жилищного права осуществляЕТ(ЮТ)ся в указанные часы». Очень хотелось бы узнать, уважаемый alex, какое отношение имеет род существительных к сказуемому, выраженному глаголом НАСТОЯЩЕГО времени? Вы, очевидно, имели в виду сказуемое - глагол прошедшего времени?